# jQuery exclude a portion of content using .not()

Tags: jquery

```
.find('.woocommerce-tabs').not('.tabs').html();
```

Above is a portion of jQuery used to find a class but exclude `.tabs` which is a child of the `.woocommerce-tabs` element.

But still `.tabs` shows up in the output which is not what I want.

**example html output**

```
<div class="woocommerce-tabs">
    <ul class="tabs">

        <li class="description_tab active">
            <a href="#tab-description">Description</a>
        </li>


        <li class="additional_information_tab">
            <a href="#tab-additional_information">Additional Information</a>
        </li>

    </ul>

    <div class="panel entry-content" id="tab-description" style="display: block;">

        <h2>Product Description</h2>

        <ul>
            <li>Robust</li>
            <li>Continuous 360° turntable rotation</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="panel entry-content" id="tab-additional_information" style="display: none;">

        <h2>Additional Information</h2>

        <table class="shop_attributes">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="">
                    <th>Tires (foam-filled)</th>
                    <td>
                        <p>16"</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="">
                    <th>Weight (kg)</th>
                    <td>
                        <p>6950</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you perhaps post the html for it?

Comment: @Joseph html example added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code filters the elements that don't have `tabs` className, it doesn't exclude the specified element from the html output. You can `.clone()` the element, remove the descendant and then call the `.html()` method.

```
.find('.woocommerce-tabs').clone().find('.tabs').remove().end().html();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aT7zX/

Answer (score 0):

Try [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```
.find('.woocommerce-tabs').not(':has(.tabs)').html();
```

`.not(':has(.tabs)')` not select element which has element with class `tabs`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to clone your `.woocommerce-tabs` and remove `.tabs` from clone element.

```
var clone = $'.woocommerce-tabs').clone();
clone.find('.tabs').remove();
var html = clone.html();
```

then you can use cloned `html` inside your code:

```
.find('.woocommerce-tabs').not('.tabs').html(html);
```